# Bug in rendering pre with long lines

Tags: bug, design, markdown

From an off-topic post here recently on Meta I found this strange rendering of code blocks encapsulated with `<pre>` and `<br>` combined on one line. If you spread the tags on two lines, it does format better, but still a little odd.

Sample code used:

```
My code about path is:
<br><pre>
        try {
            Connection baglanti = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/aaaaaaaaaa", "bbb", "aaa");

                    + " select p.ad,p.gorev,p.sicilno,s.servisadi from personel as p,servistablosu as s where p.servisid=s.servisid"
        }
</pre>
```

Which renders like this:

> [image: screen shot]

See the [current result in the Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288417/245360).

Although it is a minor bug, can this be fixed?

Comment: Very strange. Looks like anything after an empty line that is indented 4 or more spaces creates another nested code block, but obviously you only really notice if the lines are long enough to scroll.